# Bootstrap Modal close button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm working on bootstrap modal when the modal is opened it has two buttons one for print the modal content, second to close the modal.

code for modal in aspx page:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">PD checks details</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="printArea" class="modal-body">
          <asp:Repeater ID="rptPDC" runat="server">
              <HeaderTemplate>
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped"> 
                        <tr>
                            <th>IDVC</th>
                            <th>Check Number</th>
                            <th>Check Date</th>
                            <th>AMTRMITHC</th>
                        </tr>
              </HeaderTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <tr>
                      <td><%#Eval("idvc") %> </td>
                      <td><%#Eval("checkNo") %> </td>
                      <td><%#Eval("checkDa") %> </td>
                      <td><%#Eval("art") %> </td>
                  </tr>


              </ItemTemplate>
              <FooterTemplate>

                   </table>
              </FooterTemplate>

          </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="PrintElem('printArea')">Print</button>
 <button type="button" id="closemodal"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the problem is when the user click print button every thing is ok and modal content will be printed, but when the user click in close button to close the modal after print the content nothing happen the modal doesn't closed?

i tried to use the following javascript code to hid the modal:

```
  $("#closemodal").click(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        });
```

but also nothing the same problem still?

Comment: check the develop console , data-dismiss should have worked

Comment: No errors in console, it hides the modal element but the background overlay element still exists when using the javascript to hid the modal

Answer (score 0):

You no need to bind event to close explicitly. It's inbuilt in bootstrap itself. Look at the sample code carefully at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Yes, i know that, but in my case when i click outside the modal or close button nothing happens !?

Comment: No error, but it hides the modal but the background overlay element still exists when using the JavaScript code to hide it

Answer (score 0):

its working with your code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            Launch demo modal
        </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">PD checks details</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="printArea" class="modal-body">
          <asp:Repeater ID="rptPDC" runat="server">
              <HeaderTemplate>
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped"> 
                        <tr>
                            <th>IDVC</th>
                            <th>Check Number</th>
                            <th>Check Date</th>
                            <th>AMTRMITHC</th>
                        </tr>
              </HeaderTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <tr>
                      <td><%#Eval("idvc") %> </td>
                      <td><%#Eval("checkNo") %> </td>
                      <td><%#Eval("checkDa") %> </td>
                      <td><%#Eval("art") %> </td>
                  </tr>


              </ItemTemplate>
              <FooterTemplate>

                   </table>
              </FooterTemplate>

          </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="PrintElem('printArea')">Print</button>
 <button type="button" id="closemodal"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
      </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m1tL84gw/

Comment: In my side when print options dialog appears either i click cancel or print then i tried to click close button on modal it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap finds the element with attribute **data-dismiss="modal"** and trigger click on it to close modal dialog

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a `console.log('test')` when you hit the modal close button, if you get it then you can able to trigger the modal close button. For Eg:

```
$("#closemodal").click(function () {
    console.log('MOdal CLose Layer');
    setTimeout(function(){$("#myModal").modal("hide");},1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even check this  `Demo` http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/ . Closing of modal is handled by bootstrap itself. Or just double check your code of PrintElem('printArea') function. It might be possible that something inside the function is breaking the close functionality of modal.

**Update**: Use below script for printing and it will work:

```
<script>
  function PrintElem(elem) {
  var toPrint;
  toPrint=window.open();
  toPrint.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
  toPrint.print();
  toPrint.close();
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: What can be the problem with printElem function, i just examined it:
`      function PrintElem(elem) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML;
            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
          
        }
`

Comment: Hi @faresAyyad, there is a problem with printElem function. Problem is with line "document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;" To check it write below lines of script and you'll know cause of the problem : function PrintElem(elem) {
  var originalContents = $("html").html();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;  
  }  Here, even while assigning the same html text to the body it makes close or the cross icon unclickable.

Comment: it doesn't work on IE just in chrome and with no styles?!

Comment: i tried to update printElem function by adding window.close() but also the modal doesn't closed!!